# why cannot we drop the absolute continuity condition

Tags: measure-theory

Lemma:

Let $\mu: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)\to [0,\infty)$ be a measure such that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_N$, and let $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be such that the lower derivative $(\underline{D}\mu)(x)\leq r$ holds for all $x\in A$. Then $\mu(A)\leq r\lambda(A)$ holds.

Here $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra.

Why cannot we drop the condition "$\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda_N$"?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop it: $\mu$ is a finite Borel-measure on a Polish space, so it is regular. Using the Vitali-Besicovitch covering theorem instead of the Vitali covering theorem the implication can be proved, see for instance Proposition 2.21 in *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* by Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara.